# Referencing external module in typescript - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'general'

Tags: typescript, amd

I prepared these two files:

1st one is general.d.ts file

```
interface IgeneralStatic {
    General: {
        Langs: any;
    };
}

declare var general: IgeneralStatic;

declare module 'general' {
    export = general;
}
```

2nd one is just something.ts file where i'm trying to import a file alias:

```
/// <reference path="general.d.ts" />

import general = require('general');

export class SpecificLangs extends general.General.Langs
  ...
}
```

When i trying to compile it i'm getting this error:

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'general'
```

The reason of this that I don't know where is my module and I can't import it for typescript usage. It is resolved on requirejs side as package. So there is no way to reference, using import, original general.ts file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition works, in that you can import it...

For example, I can reference `Langs` like so:

```
var x = general.General.Langs;
```

However, you haven't declared that `Langs` is a class, so you can't extend it as if it were one.

If it *is* implemented in a way that allows you to extend it, declaring it as a class will allow it to be used as a base class (simplified example to demonstrate that using a class works):

```
declare module 'general' {
    export module General {
        export class Langs {


        }
    }
}
```